# Having an estimate $\hat{p}$ of $p$, what can we say about $1-\hat{p}$?

Tags: probability, estimation

First, let us define:

- $\epsilon$-additive approximation:
  $$
  \hat{p} \in \big[ p -\epsilon, \ p + \epsilon \big]
  $$
- $\epsilon$-multiplicative approximation:
  $$
  \hat{p} \in \big[ p \cdot (1-\epsilon), \ p \cdot (1+\epsilon) \big]
  $$

---

Suppose we have a randomized procedure which estimates (in a multiplicative sense) the probability $p$ of obtaining heads:
$$
\Pr \bigg[ \hat{p} \in \big[ p\cdot(1-\epsilon), \ p \cdot (1+\epsilon) \big] \bigg] \geq 1 - \delta
$$
Naturally, the probability of obtaining tails is $1 - p$.

What can we say about the estimate of the probability of tails: $1-\hat{p}$?

More generally, if we have a multiplicative estimate of some probability quantity $\hat{p}$, what is the behaviour of $1-\hat{p}$, that is, when is $1-\hat{p}$ still a multiplicative estimate, and when it becomes an additive estimate?

Can we derive a threshold, in terms of $\epsilon$ to specify this? For instance:
$$
\begin{cases}
1-\hat{p}: \text{multiplicative estimate, if} \ \hat{p} \leq T(\epsilon) \\
1-\hat{p}: \text{additive estimate, if} \ \hat{p} > T(\epsilon)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I don't follow your discussion about additive vs. multiplicative estimators (which should equally apply to $\hat p$). It seems obvious that $1-\hat p$ is an estimator of $1-p$ with the same properties as $\hat p$ (bias, efficiency...)

Comment: @YvesDaoust - if $\hat{p}$ is a **multiplicative** estimate of $p$, then is it true to simply say that $1-\hat{p}$ is also a **multiplicative** estimate of $1-p, \ (\forall) p \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: Please define these terms.

Comment: Given that $\hat{p}$ is an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $p$, I am asking if $1-\hat{p}$ will be an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $1-p$. If that's not the case, then for what values of $\hat{p} \in [0, 1]$ will $1-\hat{p}$ remain an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate and for what values it will become an $\epsilon$-additive estimate?

Comment: If one of the estimators is multiplicative on one side and additive on the other, the other behaves symmetrically.

Comment: Can you please point out how to formally prove this?

Comment: Can you prove the property for $\hat p$ ?

Comment: So, you mean to prove: If $\hat{p}$ is an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $p$, then $1-\hat{p}$ is an $\epsilon$-additive estimate of $1-p$, $(\forall) \ p \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: No, "the estimator is multiplicative on one side and additive on the other".

Comment: What does "multiplicative on one side" mean, formally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:**

If $\hat{p}$ is an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $p$, then if $p \leq 1/2$, we have that $1-\hat{p}$ is also a multiplicative estimate of $1-p$.

**Proof:**

If $\hat{p}$ is an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $p$, then:
$$
\hat{p} \in \big[ p\cdot(1-\epsilon), \ p\cdot(1+\epsilon) \big] \implies 1-\hat{p} \in \big[ 1 - p\cdot(1+\epsilon), \ p\cdot(1-\epsilon) \big]
$$

For $1-\hat{p}$ to be an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $1-p$, the following must hold:
$$
(1-p)\cdot(1-\epsilon) \leq 1-\hat{p} \leq (1-p)\cdot(1+\epsilon)
$$

Considering $1-\hat{p} = 1-p\cdot(1+\epsilon)$, we get:
$$
(1-p)\cdot(1-\epsilon) \leq 1-p\cdot(1+\epsilon) \leq (1-p)\cdot(1+\epsilon)
$$
From the first inequality we get:
$$
1-\epsilon-p+\epsilon p \leq 1-p -\epsilon p \\
2\epsilon p \leq \epsilon \\
\color{blue}{p \leq 1/2}
$$
From the second inequality we get:
$$
1-p -\epsilon p \leq 1+\epsilon-p-\epsilon p \\
\color{blue}{0 \leq \epsilon}
$$

Analogous for $1-\hat{p} = 1-p\cdot(1-\epsilon)$.

$\blacksquare$

---

More generally it can be shown that $1-\hat{p}$ is a $\lambda$-multiplicative estimate of $1-p$, given that $\hat{p}$ is an $\epsilon$-multiplicative estimate of $p$, if:
$$
p \leq \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \epsilon}
$$